# TypeError: missing arguments in custom Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why am I getting the following error in this python code?

```py
class polygon:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def display_info_polygon(self):
        print("it contains 5 sides")
    
    def perimeter_of_polygon(self):
        perimeter = sum(self.sides)
        return perimeter
    
class triangle(polygon):
    def display_info_triangle(self):
        print("Triangle has 3 sides")
    
class square(polygon):
    def display_info_square(self):
        print("square has 4 sides")
    
triangle1 = triangle()
triangle1.display_info_triangle()
```

This is the Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\CISPL-ABHINITESH\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\perimeter_polygon_inheritance.py", line 20, in  triangle1 = triangle() TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sides'

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a class that takes one agr `polygon` but you're not giving it that value that's why it displays an error.

Your code:

```
triangle1 = triangle()
triangle1.display_info_triangle()
```

How it should be:

```
triangle1 = triangle(<YOUR POLYGON VALUE>)
triangle1.display_info_triangle()
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the Exception:

```
triangle1 = triangle() 
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sides'
```

That means, when calling `triangle()`, the method `__init__()` of the parent class is called, which is missing one argument. So, the solution is to add that argument in the call:

```
triangle1 = triangle(3)
```

replace 3 with the value you want the argument `sides` to have.

Answer (score 0):

`triangle` is inheriting `polygon`, so when you create an instance of `triangle`, the constructor of `polygon` is initiated, which takes an argument `sides`.

```
def __init__(self, sides):
      self.sides = sides
```

If you don't pass that argument, you will get an error. You should instantiate triangle by giving a `sides` value as an argument to the constructor like so:

```
triangle1 = triangle(7)
```